# Hibernate SQLQuery doesn't INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: java, hibernate

When I do an executeUpdate on this SQL query in Hibernate 3.5:

```
Query insert = session.createSQLQuery(
"INSERT INTO unmapped_table_1 (column_name) "
    + "SELECT column_name "
    + "FROM source_table;");
insert.executeUpdate();
```

Hibernate returns the number of entries but does not insert the entries.
When I do the query directly on the MySQL Server, the entries do get inserted.

Comment: Are you properly committing the transaction?

Comment: Set the `hibernate.show_sql=true`, what is the log output for query execution?

Comment: Have you tried `select columns into unmapped_table_1 from source_table`. ?

Comment: Call transaction commit after your code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your autocommit is not set to true, in this case you have to call `commit()` after query execution. By default Hibernate auto commit is false you can set autocommit to true with`setAutocommit(true)`